# Trigger code execution if element exist in page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the javascript below:

```
$(document).on('click', '#layer_cart .cross, #layer_cart .continue, .layer_cart_overlay', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.layer_cart_overlay').hide();
    $('#layer_cart').fadeOut('fast');                
    location.reload();
});
```

I want to create if statement with location.reload. If system find #divforexample in source code then reaload the page. I think I need to use

```
elem = document.getElementById("divforexample ");
```

Or I'm wrong ? Thanks for help.

Online: https://jsfiddle.net/wu7qqns0/#&togetherjs=bI8oGhhQB4

solved for me:

```
var x = document.getElementById("reload");
            if (x){
                location.reload();                    
            }
```

Comment: do you want to check on page load or during a specific event? anyway use .find(). You will trigger it on click, on load or in any other moment depending on what your desired behaviuour is

Comment: you can use polling. You will trigger function in a interval then you will check the condition you have mentioned. (Usage of setInterval function)

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = document.getElementById("reload");
            if (x){
                location.reload();                    
            }
```